# Playing one Video at a time in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am designing list of videos scrollable page in xamarin forms i want to play the video which its position is at the center of the page only all other videos in the list paused (like facebook watch idea).
I tried Collection View and Carousel view but this mission failed. Any idea?

Comment: Please show us what you’ve tried and describe the specific problem you had with it

Comment: Please provide more details and show relevant parts of your code (as text!): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What control did you choose to display the video?